# var keyword without 'using someNamespace'

Tags: c#, using, var

How does Visual Studio/intellisense know what to do with a variable declared as `var` even if you don't include the necessary `using` declaration at the top?

For example, I have class `MyDomainObject` defined in a different namespace
If I don't declare `using TheOtherNameSpace;` in the file the following code won't compile:

```
private void Foo()
{
   MyDomainObject myObj = new MyDomainObject(); 
   // Doesn't know what this class is
}
```

But if I use `var`

```
var myObj = new MyDomainObject();
```

This will compile, and intellisense knows exactly what I can with it.

So how the heck does it know what the type is without the `using`?

(And as an aside, if it knows without the `using`, why do we need `using`s at all?!)

Comment: Can you post the actual code from your program in both cases? I doubt you really have a method named Foo and a class named MyDomainObject, perhaps the real code can shed some light on it.

Comment: Sorry, not working for me ... it does not compile in any case

Comment: See Jon Skeet's answer for the situation I was encountering in my real code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example with a constructor won't work, but a slightly more involved situation will. For example, suppose you have three types:

- class Foo in namespace N1
- class Bar in namespace N2
- class Baz in namespace N3

Now suppose `Bar` has a method which returns an instance of `Foo`:

```
public static Foo GetFoo() { ... }
```

Here, Bar.cs would need a using directive for N1, unless it specified the name in full.

Now suppose that we have this code in Baz:

```
using N2;
...
var foo = Bar.GetFoo();
```

That will compile, but

```
using N2;
...
Foo foo = Bar.GetFoo();
```

won't. The reason is that using directives are only there so that the compiler knows what the name "Foo" means - what its fully qualified name is. In the first snippet, `Bar.GetFoo()` is effectively declared to return `N1.Foo`, so the compiler is fine. In the second snippet, the compiler first sees "Foo" and doesn't know anything about N1, so doesn't know how to look it up.

Comment: Thanks Jon, both for the answer and for managing to understand the question given my poor example

Answer (score 6):

Short answer is that it doesn't.

There must be some other reason for the behavior and difference you're seeing.

Can you reproduce the problem with a short, but complete, program so that you could post it here?

There is nothing magical about the `var` keyword, it simply infers the type needed based on the expression on the right hand side of the assignment (in this case), so there is no reason why one of the code pieces should work better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

It knows the fully-qualified type of the object because this type is in one of the referenced assemblies.

`using SomeNamespace` is only a shorthand making it possible to say `MyType` instead of `SomeNamespace.MyType`.